# PHP & MySQL page speed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just have a general question.  I am concerned with the speed of my PHP website, which is set to go into production soon.

My concern is the length of time it takes for the page to run a query.

On my page, I have about 14 filters in an HTML form.  I am using the method GET to retrieve all the values from the filters.  Granted, not all 14 filters have to be used.  A user can just search off one filter.  Of course, the more filters are selected, the larger the query becomes.  But the larger the query becomes, the quicker the page loads.  So it's beneficial for the user to select more filters over using just one filter.

All of the filter values are then sent to an INCLUDED PHP file, which then builds a query based off of the user's filtered selection.

The query runs and I am able to print the selected data into an HTML table on the original page.  The problem is the it can take quite some time for the page to render and finally display the data-table.

The database is not too large.  Maybe between 20K - 40K records, though there are over 20 columns per record.

When I run the same query in MySQL, it returns the data faster than it does on the page.

Here is where I believe the problem might lie.

Within the form are the filters.  About 5-6 of the filters are running queries themselves to populate the selection data for the user.

I believe that after the user runs a query, the page refreshes and it has to re-run all the filter queries within the form.

If this is the case, what steps can I take to fix this issue?  If any.  Should I place all of the filters in a separate file and INCLUDE them within the form?  If not, then please advise what I can do to speed up the page loading process.

I have visited various websites in an attempt to fix this issue.  Like this one:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/top-20-mysql-best-practices--net-7855

I am following just about every step suggested by that site, but I am still experiencing the page load delay.

I hope I can receive some positive insight.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ask this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com you will get proper answer there

Comment: My gut says you are doing something like `SELECT * FROM yourTable`, doing this can slow down the speed. Another thing is 20 columns is quite a lot, think about your user versus your ease of coding. Would most users need all 20 parts by default?

Comment: I am not using SELECT * for the queries, I am listing out each column header.  The funny thing with the table is that it joined to another VIEW_TABLE, which increases the overall columns to almost 50 columns.  Granted, I am not printing all 50 to the page, although some of the columns are used populate popover data, which comes from the INNER JOINS.

Comment: If you use google chrome try the PageSpeed Insights (by Google) plugin. this will tell you where you can imporove page speed. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/pagespeed%20insights?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon. I know this might has nothing to do with your filters but it might help you

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is if all the filters are static and do not disappear or change view when selected / changed value you can set the filters outside of the reload view.

Currently I am building a site that is dealing with AJAX query reload and have to deal with a very similar aspect. My fields are set outside of the reload and I have very fast load times.

If they are dynamic or need to change based on options chosen then I would set them as a separate reload. Basically determining which ones changed vs what needs to be displayed.

Hopefully this helps and explains well enough.

Comment: Your response shed a little light.  When I run a search, most of the time, the filters disappear from the screen.  They reappear once the page is finished loading and the data-table is loaded.  What does this mean?

Comment: You might have the filters in the "reload zone" still. Basically you want to take all filters out of the div / table element that is replaced by the data. This way they are only called and implemented at the beginning of your site load. When you search it should (assuming AJAX) submit to your query file without refreshing the page. Now if you are refreshing the whole page every time this will not work and you will have the load times every time. AJAX is your best chance to reduce load times with multiple queries / searches.

Comment: I have been wanting to utilize AJAX.  I think now would be the time.  I just hope I don't have to re-code my whole site.

Comment: you shouldn't have to. It is more like moving sections around. There is a TON of easy to use and follow guides that I haven't even scratched the surface of. So get in there and hopefully you'll be good to go.